# gunicorn3 does not recognize new mysql entries

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, gunicorn

I made a Python Flask Web Application that lists MySQL database entries via SQLAlchemy.
I used two ways to start the application: python3 and gunicorn3.
What happens:

**python3:**

When I add new entries to the database and then open up the Web Application, I can see all Entries.

**gunicorn3:**

When I add new entries to the database and then open up the Web Application, I can see all Entries except the new ones.
When I restart the gunicorn3 web server or the MySQL server, I can see all Entries.

Before I used python2 and unicorn, everything worked fine.

Comment: how many processes are you running? are you using some cache before the database?

Comment: only one process. and the application does a mysql query each time i reload. so i think i am not using any cache.

Comment: I guess it must be something with transactions. Try adding an explicit commit where you store your new entries to see if it helps. If it does, then you transactions are wrong indeed. If it does not help, then it probably isn't caused by transactions.